# What process is the parent process of containerd-shim?

Tags: minikube, containerd, runc, docker-daemon

I setup 2 k8s environments with minikube. One with the `--container-runtime=docker` flag and one with `--container-runtime=containerd` flag. Here are the differences I see.

When I set `container-runtime=docker` , these things happen

1. there is a `dockerd` service that is running
2. The `dockerd` service spawns `containerd` as its own child
3. There are `/usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2` processes that run the actual containers, and the **parent of each of these `containerd-shim-runc-v2` is PID 1 on the system.**

When I set `container-runtime=containerd`, these things happen

1. there is no `dockerd` service, no ambiguities there.
2. there is a `containerd` process, which is *owned* by PID 1. Again, no surprises there.
3. There are `containerd-shim` processes that run actual containers, and the **parent of each of these `containerd-shim` processes is `containerd`**

So here are my questions

1. What are the differences between `containerd-shim` and `containerd-shim-runc-v2` ? They seem to take mostly similar flags etc.
2. Why in scenario 1 the *shims are children of PID 1* whereas scenario 2 the *shims are children of containerd* ?

EDIT: Just thought of an edit. On a ubuntu 20 box, if I install docker, dockerd is a separate process whose parent is PID 1, containerd is a separate process whose parent is PID 1, and all containers are children of container-shim-runc-v2 whose PID is 1 ?!?! Why is `containerd` not a child of `dockerd` ? Where is this configured?

Comment: Hello @HariSundararajan. Could you tell us which version of Minikube are you using?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor the latest. v1.20.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have dug into this topic and came to the following conclusions and sources.

**1. What are the differences between containerd-shim and containerd-shim-runc-v2? They seem to take mostly similar flags etc.**

These are just different versions, `containerd-shim-runc-v2` being the newest version of the `containerd-shim`. See the source code [here](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/tree/master/runtime).

It looks like that docker still uses `containerd-shim` instead of `containerd-shim-runc-v2`. The base functionality will still be the same function of the shim, being that the shim monitors runc containers to tell containerd when runc has finished a run time.

If you are concerned about differences in the API, please reference the source code. But in functionality they are just different versions of the shim API.

---

**2. Why in scenario 1 the shims are children of PID 1 whereas scenario 2 the shims are children of containerd?**

Ultimately, they are both children of PID 1 where the shims are children of containerd which is a child of PID 1.

[This blog post](https://www.threatstack.com/blog/diving-deeper-into-runtimes-kubernetes-cri-and-shims) gives a good overview of runtimes on k8s and worker nodes. Particularly, the sections on Docker, containerd and shims will give more perspective on your questions.

> The shim sits between the container manager and a runtime to
> facilitate communication and prevent integration problems that may
> arise. It allows for daemon-less containers. It basically sits as the
> parent of the container’s processes to facilitate communications, and
> eliminates the long-running runtime processes for containers. The
> processes of the shim and the container are bound tightly; however,
> they are totally separated from the process of the container manager.

[Here](https://nanikgolang.netlify.app/post/containers/) is a more thorough resource into containerd, shims, and how they interact with linux.

And [this resource](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/implementing-container-runtime-shim/) dives into runc, containerd and their PIDs in linux.